How is the "To Path" Operation in TikZ implemented?
Since I would like to convert some 2D Drawings I have made with TikZ to something that OpenSCAD understands (I already tried converting the LaTeX PDF Output to svg and importing that, but this lead to many hard to solve problems for my use case), I was wondering how the "To Path" Operation is actually implemented in the TikZ backend. 
So far, the pgf/TikZ Manual was not giving me enough information regarding to that topic; section 14.13 just states:

..., if you write (a) to [out=135,in=45] (b) a curve is added to the path, which leaves at an angle of 135° at a and arrives at an angle of 45° at b. This is because the options in and out trigger a special path to be used instead of the straight line.

Question:
Can anyone give more low-level details or point me in the right direction where I have to search in the Source Code?
Addendum: Why am I asking this question?
When originally posting the question, I did not add a detailed explanation why I would like to understand the TikZ implementation, since the origin of my problems lies within the constraints of OpenSCAD (and therefor is completely off-topic on a LaTeX forum). However, my mentioning of svg seemed to have caused more confusion than it helped, so I decided to describe the problem in more detail.
The Goal
I have drawn some complex 2D Shapes in TikZ using the to syntax, which now should be used as 2D Sketches in OpenSCAD for extruding a 3D Object.
Initial Idea
OpenSCAD can import a variety of 2D Drawing Formats, including svg. In the past, I have used Inkscape successfully to convert from PDF to svg, imported the resulting file into OpenSCAD and applied the extrusion. The conversion and import worked well, although dvisvgm as mentioned by @David Carlisle and @Qrrbrbirlbel in the comments might be a cleaner way of doing this. As long as I would just need a normal extrusion, everything would have been done. However, for this specific object I am working on right now I need to apply a special form of non-linear extrusion, for which I require access to the "vertex" information of the object. Unfortunately, OpenSCAD does neither provide a way to access the points of an imported object nor a way to convert an object to points.
Attempted Solutions:
Attempt 1: Convert svg to points externally
I used a Python Script to convert the svg path information to a set of 2D points that could be loaded by OpenSCAD. After some tweaking, I could produce a valid output and extrude the object with OpenSCAD. However, there were issues with scaling, distortion, offsets and order of path operations. Perhaps exporting directly with dvisvgm might have helped, but the importing of multiple shapes and combining them in OpenSCAD still would have been a nightmare.
Attempt 2: Implementation of TikZ logic in OpenSCAD
Since it is possible in OpenSCAD to use Bézier Curves (and implement your own logic), I was hoping that the implementation of to in TikZ is based upon Bézier Curves and some "simple" math, that I could try to implement in OpenSCAD. For that, I would need a good understanding of the TikZ Implementation, for which this question is the starting point.

The to path operation simply “executes” the path specified by the to path key (which just stores its argument in \tikz@to@path) while having set up \tikztostart, \tikztotarget and \tikztonodes accordingly. It does a few things more (including some hooks and things) but that doesn't have anything to do with what path will be actually drawn. The real power comes from what ever the argument to to path does with \tikztostart and \tikztotarget.

All the bends, loops and outs and ins are actually defined in the always-loaded topaths library, its source is tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex. Here you can see how it calculates the real starting and end points (in case of them being non-coordinate nodes) and the control points of the Bézier curve. Meaning, all default curves you can produce with to are just simply .. controls … .. curves.

rather than convert pdf to svg you may do better to use dvisvgm, tikz has support for direct conversion to svg

I didn't see SVG being mentioned. In that case, I second what David said. The manual does mention that as well. Though, you will find also examples on this site.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for your comment; it pointed me in the right direction. The svg mentioned was one attempt which did not work due to the way I would have to process the data in OpenSCAD. Converting from PDF to svg was actually working really well; but I have to agree with David Carlisle/you that using the internal method would be cleaner. Since the problems are due to implementation constraints in OpenSCAD, I did not want to go off-topic explaining them in great detail. In hindsight, this seemed to have caused some confusion, so I added the information to the original question.
